# How to test if a critical section is locked, without entering it? Or, how to wait until a critsec is owned by another thread?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, deadlock

I am working on forcing certain deadlock scenarios to reproduce consistently, for dev purposes. In doing so it would be helpful to be able for a thread to wait until a critical section is locked by another thread, then forcing it to block.

So, I want something like:

```
void TryToWaitForBlock(CriticalSection& cs, DWORD ms)
{
    // wait until this CS is blocked, then return
}

...

void someFunction()
{
    // ...
    TryToWaitForBlock(cs, 5000);// this will give much more time for the crit sec to block by other threads, increasing the chance that the next call will block.
    EnterCriticalSection(cs);// normally this /very/ rarely blocks. When it does, it deadlocks.
    // ...
}
```

`TryEnterCriticalSection` *would* be perfect, but because it will actually enter the critical section, it is not usable. Is there a similar function that will do the test, but NOT also try to enter it?

Comment: Can you not just release it immediately if `TryEnterCriticalSection` manages to enter it?

Comment: hrm, my instinct was that `TryEnter...` was too disruptive in the flow of events. But thinking about it, it should have no effect, especially for this temp debug code. It also eliminates a race condition if the critsec becomes available between my two calls. Now I would just have one call like, `EnterCritSecButTryToBlockFirst()`. Thanks for the second-guessing :)

Comment: Actually the race condition would still exist. But it's not a big deal in this context. Man my brain is fried :/

Comment: If you can change the code of other threads then you could do something like `WaitForSingleObject(event);EnterCriticalSection(cs)` in `someFunction()` and `EnterCriticalSection(cs);SetEvent(event)`. In that case your thread in `someFunction()` will block as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool TryToWaitForBlock( CRITICAL_SECTION& cs, DWORD ms ) 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency( &freq );

    LARGE_INTEGER now;
    QueryPerformanceCounter( &now );

    LARGE_INTEGER waitTill;
    waitTill.QuadPart = static_cast<LONGLONG>(now.QuadPart + freq.QuadPart * (ms / 1000.0));

    while( now.QuadPart < waitTill.QuadPart ) {
        if( NULL != static_cast<volatile HANDLE&>(cs.OwningThread) ) {
            return true;
        }

        QueryPerformanceCounter( &now );
    }

    return false;
}
```